# Jquery how to hide other visible divs on click

Tags: jquery

Two questions please:

1)  In this example, http://jsbin.com/ijuli, how do I make it so when one image is clicked, the other un-hidden .clickSave divs go back to hidden.

2)  Is there a more efficient way to write the JS code?

Jquery

```
$(".clickSave").hide();  
    $(".one").click(function() {
    $(".clickSave.one").toggle(); 
});

$(".clickSave").hide();  
    $(".two").click(function() {
    $(".clickSave.two").toggle(); 
});

$(".clickSave").hide();  
    $(".three").click(function() {
    $(".clickSave.three").toggle(); 
});
```

Thank you so much in advance! I'm so confused by all this.

Comment: Also, I know that there shouldn't be a <div> in the <a> tag - I didn't get to change that on jsbin example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to be more generic like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".clickSave").hide();
    $(".choose-theme-bar ul li a").click(function() {
      $(this).find(".clickSave").toggle() //toggle current
       .end().parent().siblings().find(".clickSave").hide(); //hide others
    });
});
```

[You can view an updated version of your demo here](http://jsbin.com/ijuli/4)

Comment: Quick question:  When I remove the DIV from inside the <a> tags, it stops working?  Can you tell me how to remedy this?  Thanks!

Comment: @adamwstl: It stops working because then you have no element with class `clickSave` anymore. Hence, jQuery cannot select one.

Comment: @adamwstl - Can you post the new markup? If it's *beside* the anchor, just change `$(this).find(".clickSave")` to `$(this).siblings(".clickSave")`, or change the click handler to the `<li>` by removing the "` a`" at the end of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickSave").hide();

    $("a").click(function() {  // attaches click handler to links       
        // toggle clickSave element inside the clicked link
        var ele = $(".clickSave", this).toggle();
        // hide all other visible clickSave elements
        $(".clickSave:visible").not(ele).hide(); 
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ijuli/6)

Comment: This would hide all of them, every time ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yeah, I just realized it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 $('.clickSave').click( function() {
    $('.clickSave').hide()
    $(this).show()
 })
```

Comment: Generally speaking `$(this).show()` shouldn't ever appear *directly* in the body of a `click` handler...what did you click on if it wasn't there already? ;)  Also, semi-colons, **always**!