# jquery append when a div is visible

Tags: jquery, html, append

So my  container div when is not visible  is this :

```
div id="content-wrapper" style="display: block; left: -980px; ">
```

and when is visible is this :

```
div id="content-wrapper" style="display: block; left:0px; ">
```

I want to append a div when a div container is visible, and I don't know how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you're using a position instead of hiding the div?
If you hid the div (style="display: none;") then you could use the :visible selector in jQuery.
You could also use a class (class="hidden") then you could use jQuery to see:

```
if ($('#content-wrapper').hasClass('hidden'))
{
    // append div
}
```

Without that, you're pretty much dead in the water as you don't want to rely on spacing or text case.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#content-wrapper:visible")` will return #content-wrapper when visible.

using the visible selector:

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

So you could do something like `$("#content-wrapper:visible").append(...)`

Related to:

[how to check image is visible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613844/how-to-check-image-is-visible-or-not)

[Check if divs are visible with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315458/check-if-divs-are-visible-with-jquery)

[How to determine if a table row is visible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554378/how-to-find-out-a-table-row-it-is-visible-or-not)

Comment: I *think* "visibility" is being achieved by position `left: -980px;`, which the `:visible` selector wouldn't take into account.